# To retain address obtained from GPS in both orientations with 2 xmls

Tags: android

In my application the address obtained from GPS must be retained in both orientations.Every time I change the orientation the GPS starts fetching from the beginning.

I have used 2 xmls for landscape and potrait...i.e layout-land...
I have used android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" in manifest to retain GPS result.

Result is retained but landscape xml is not used instead potrait xml is used for both orientations.

If i remove android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" from manifest GPS starts fetching location from beggining.

Please help me regarding this...

Answer (score 0):

Could you post some more code. How are you starting your location listener? It doesn't make sense that removing android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" should make your GPS receive a signal. Maybe it was chance that you received a location update while inside. Maybe you should try testing the app outdoors.

Comment: No this code android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" does not affect GPS..But my question is once the location is obtained why the location is not retained when i change the tab's orientation... When the orientation changes activity is restarted..

Comment: I'm by no means an expert on the android OS but I get the best results if I register a separate Service (rather than an Activity) to deal with GPS location updates. This way the OS is less likely to kill the process and a few other advantages. Your application can, of course, still communicate with the Service.

Comment: Can you please help me with a sample code for this seperate Service..,

Comment: Do you only need the gps to be running when the application is open? Or do you need the process to run all the time?